# vue packages not seen in sublime text 3 package control

Tags: windows, vue.js, sublimetext3, vuetify.js

I'm trying to install/add vue libraries in sublime so it would recognize the vue file type.

I'm using windows.

I followed the instructions stated in the packages, it says open the package control and search vue packages. But when I do a search, no vue related packages appear.

I also tried to do the **package control: add repository** by adding this: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-sublime, but still the same result. I'm not able to see vue options in the package control.

I'm sure that the github repository is added in sublime because when I chose **package control: remove repository**, it does list the link that I added.

I also tried to manually download the .package file and store  them in the packages folder of sublime but I find no option to download the .package file for vuetify.

I also tried to reinstall sublime but it didn't worked. Also I pulled my hair and banged the table real hard still didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to ctrl_shift+p, then package control: install package, then it will show another input box. then you would see there the items for vue

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the repo

1. ctrl+shif+p
2. Package Control: Add Repository
3. At the bottom of the editor windo paste https://github.com/lucasnasm/vuetify-sublime.git
4. Hit enter
5. ctrl+shift+p
6. Package Control: Install Package
7. Search vuetify-sublime
8. Click and it will install

This worked for me, hope it helps someone else! Unfortunately issues are disabled on th repo and the readme is not much help.